# Express is not redirecting my post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

So I am building a MERN application, I am still in the early phase where I am testing the API and all.

In Express I have **authorizationController** and **userController**.
When I test the API in Express using a plain html file that has a form that send a post request to **"/register"**, everything worked fine. But when I included React and started calling the API from my React app, it stopped working the way it is intended.

This is my code:
I have a **/register** route that will take a post request to hash the password and redirect it to **/api/users**
this is the code of the function called at the **/register** route:

```
exports.registerUser = async (req, res) => {
  const hashedPassword = md5(req.body.password);
  const newUser = new User({
    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    dateOfBirth: req.body.dateOfBirth,
    address: req.body.address,
    email: req.body.email,
    phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
    hash: hashedPassword,
  });
  req.session.newUser = newUser;
  console.log(req.session.newUser);
  await res.redirect(307, "/api/users");
};
```

this is the function that gets called when it gets redirected to **/api/users**

```
exports.createUser = (req, res) => {
  console.log("this api has been called");
  if (!req.session.newUser) {
    res.redirect("/");
    return;
  }
  const newUser = new User(req.session.newUser);
  // console.log(newUser);
  newUser
    .save()
    .then((data) => {
      res.status(200).redirect("/register");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).send({ message: "An error occured." });
    });
};
```

The line `console.log("this api has been called");` is not being executed.

As I mention before, it worked fine when tested from Express itself using html file.

This is my react code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";

const initialValues = {
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  dateOfBirth: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  address: "",
  phoneNumber: "",
};

function Register() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });

    console.log({ ...values });
  };

  const handleSubmission = () => {
    console.log(values);
    axios.post("/register", values).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Register</h1>
      <form>
        <label style={{ display: "block" }}>
          First Name
          <input
            type="text"
            name="firstName"
            value={values.firstName}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label style={{ display: "block" }}>
          Last Name
          <input
            type="text"
            name="lastName"
            value={values.lastName}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label style={{ display: "block" }}>
          Date of Birth
          <input
            type="date"
            name="dateOfBirth"
            value={values.datefBirth}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>

        <label style={{ display: "block" }}>
          Email
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={values.email}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label style={{ display: "block" }}>
          Password
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            value={values.password}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label style={{ display: "block" }}>
          address
          <input
            type="text"
            name="address"
            value={values.address}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label style={{ display: "block" }}>
          Phone Number
          <input
            type="text"
            name="phoneNumber"
            value={values.phoneNumber}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>
        <button onClick={handleSubmission}>Register</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Register;
```

I do not know what is wrong with it. The first call **/register** is working fine. The redirect on **/api/users** where the data will be stored to the database is not.

**EDIT**

I have an HTML file that send a POST request to **/register**. The function `registerUser` gets called, which redirects the request to **/api/users**. This is my routes file:

```
const router = require("express").Router();

const userController = require("../controllers/userController");

router
  .route("/")
  .get(userController.getAllUsers)
  .post(userController.createUser)
  .delete(userController.deleteAllUsers);

router
  .route("/:_id")
  .get(userController.getUser)
  .put(userController.updateUser)
  .delete(userController.deleteUser);

module.exports = router;
```

When a POST request gets sent to **/api/users**, the function `createUser` gets called and a new entry is saved to my database.

When I tried this from a plain HTML file, it worked as intended. However, when I send the data to **/register** using React and Axios, the redirection does not work. The function `createUser` which is called by the **/api/users** endpoint is not being executed.

Comment: I don't see where you call `createUser`. The statements _"this is the function that gets called when it gets redirected to /`api/users`"_ and _"The line `console.log("this api has been called");` is not being executed."_ are contradicting.

Comment: it is in the routes file. When i send a POST request to **/api/users**, the function ```createUser``` gets called

Comment: So is it actually called or not? It's not clear in your question. Do you see the HTTP request in the network monitor?

Comment: I will try to clarify it in an edit. My bad.

Comment: I did an edit. I hope this clarified it a little bit.

Comment: It is not being called. I do not see anything in my network monitor. The page just refreshes.

Comment: The redirect must be executed by the browser. Ie the backend sends back the statuscode redirect, and then the browser should send another request to the server. Can you check in the browser's developer tool if that happens? And if yes, if the browser sends a `POST` or a `GET` request to the redirect-url ... Because typically `res.redirect()` sends a 302 status. And with that status, browsers change the follow-up request to GET ... If you want the follow up to be also a POST, you should return status code 307

Comment: BTW `res.status(200).redirect(...)` doesn't make any sense ... Either you want to have status code 200, which is never a redirect, or you want a redirect, which must have status 3xx ...

Answer (score 0):

Lets try the following, if you are using React, I'll suggest to handle the redirect in React if the response from the API is successful.

We need to make the `handleSubmission()` method `async` to properly wait for the API to respond.

```
const handleSubmission = async () => {
  console.log(values);
  const response = await axios.post("/register", values);

  if (response.status === 200) {
    console.log('handle redirect');
  }
};
```

Or you could just handle the routing in the `.then()` as you alreayd have setup.

```
axios.post("/register", values).then((res) => {
  console.log('handle redirect here`);
});
```

You will need to setup React Router to handle the routing to a new page, it should be straight forward, [here](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) is an example of how you could set it up.

Hope that helps.